# SQL Where clause does not filter out "Zero" values

Tags: sql, sql-server, filtering, where-clause, common-table-expression

I have two tables called Recovery and Installments.

```
Recovery ([pk] RID, emp_id, amount, duration, type]

Installments ([pk] ID, [fk] recovery_id, recovered_amount, date)
```

When an employee is granted a loan, that information is stored in `Recovery` table. This loan is then recovered installment basis, from monthly salary. (installment is `[amount /duration]`).
Once recovered, details about the installment recovered should be stored in `Installments` table. Since an loan may be recovered in several installments the relation ship of Recovery to Installment is `1:M.`

Now let's say I just want to find out all recovery details that should be deducted from Salary. I have written this query in this regard. Here I take sum of all paid installment and then deduct it from the loan amount and if the balance is greater than 0 then the installment is calculated. Expected result is `Emp_DI | Installment`

```
WITH Summary (RID, emp_id, amount, duration, installment) 

AS(

SELECT Recovery.RID, Recovery.emp_id, Recovery.amount, Recovery.duration,   SUM(Installment.recovered_installment) AS Installments
FROM Recovery LEFT OUTER JOIN
Installment ON Recovery.RID = Installment.recovery_id

WHERE Recovery.type = 'Loan'                       
GROUP BY Recovery.duration, Recovery.amount, Recovery.emp_id, Recovery.RID 
)  

SELECT emp_id, SUM(amount / duration) AS INS FROM Summary  
WHERE ((CASE WHEN installment != NULL THEN (amount-installment) 
                      ELSE(amount) END)> 0 )
GROUP BY emp_id
```

This query runs fine give the desired out put with one exception. I.e. it seems that there is an issue in WHERE clause.

```
 WHERE ((CASE WHEN installment != NULL THEN (amount-installment) 
                          ELSE(amount) END)> 0 )
```

This does not filter out the records with balance zero as expected. I couldn't understand the reason for this. So could you please help me? Your help is really appreciated!

Comment: Thank you all who answered. I was not aware of that ;) I just accepted first answer. Thanks again it really helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `is not null`:

```
 WHERE ((CASE WHEN installment IS NOT NULL THEN (amount-installment) 
               ELSE(amount) END)> 0 )
```

Almost any comparison to `NULL`, including `= NULL` and `<> NULL` returns `NULL`.  And, `NULL` is treated as false.  Use `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

The criteria `installment != NULL` needs to be replaced with `installment is not null`.

[All comparisons to NULL return FALSE.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191270(v=sql.105).aspx)

For the specific comparison you are making, this WHERE clause might be easier on the eyes:

```
WHERE (amount - COALESCE(installment,0)) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 WHERE ( installment IS NOT NULL AND (amount-installment) > 0)
     OR ( installment IS NULL AND AMOUNT >0)
```

In Sql Server NULL is an `Unknown` value, so you cant possibly compare an unknown value to any other value. therefore you use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` when checking for nulls in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to put it in the having clause? Does this work?

```
WITH Summary as
 (SELECT Recovery.RID,
         Recovery.emp_id,
         Recovery.amount,
         Recovery.duration,
         SUM(Installment.recovered_installment) AS Installments
    FROM Recovery
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Installment
      ON Recovery.RID = Installment.recovery_id
   WHERE Recovery.type = 'Loan'
   GROUP BY Recovery.duration,
            Recovery.amount,
            Recovery.emp_id,
            Recovery.RID)
SELECT emp_id, SUM(amount / duration) AS INS
  FROM Summary
 GROUP BY emp_id
having sum (CASE WHEN installments is not NULL
                 THEN(amount - installments) ELSE(amount) END) > 0
```

As others have pointed out, "is not null" is the correct way of saying not equal to null, as well.